# How to create complex CSS structures?

Tags: website-design, css

How do companies like Google, Facebook maintain their CSS files? I have looked at some of them and they are really huge, even with their names all scrambled? How do they manage to create so complex hierarchies of CSS to create those beautiful sites?

Comment: You should look into [SAS](https://sass-lang.com/) and/or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/). They both can import css file enabling you to have a neat folder structure with bunch of css files that, when compiled come out as a single css file with or without minification. You can use command line tools to compile them but I'd suggest trying [Prepros](https://prepros.io/) and/or [Codekit](https://codekitapp.com/).

Comment: This question clearly belongs on SO

Comment: @mayersdesign As it stands it belongs nowhere. Technically it's too broad. Could be UX, Code or Design.

Comment: @Ovaryraptor I did say CSS structure though. I was trying to ask how do companies create such a complex hierarchy of CSS design and maintain that.

Comment: It's not necessarily the way they do it, but in SASS, for example, you can use [import](https://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-5). This is basically the same as regular CSS [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import), with the exception that SASS is compiled into regular CSS. So in SASS `import` effectively merges multiple CSS files into one file. This alone allows you to work with a very complex CSS folder structure with different sections of an app of a website split into different CSS files. [_Check out this example_](https://codepen.io/joonaspaakko/project/editor/ZjWebo)

Answer (score 1):

### Simply by being efficient

As you said yourself they have massive libraries, they also practice, implement and actually develop techniques and methods for **efficient** CSS and web management.

I recommend going through [Google's Web Fundamentals](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/), it has a wealth of information on their ideation and processes to create a fluit and natural web experience.

---

An excellent example of one of the **many**  ways they strive to tame CSS is to [Reduce the Scope and Complexity of Style Calculations](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/reduce-the-scope-and-complexity-of-style-calculations)

One example is taking when you reference an element in your CSS with just a class:

```
.title {
  /* styles */
}
```

Taking more complex CSS that looks like this:

```
.box:nth-last-child(-n+1) .title {
  /* styles */
}
```

And simplify the selector into a class:

```
.final-box-title {
  /* styles */
}
```

---

The management also comes down to designers too. Everything from good UX design principles to animations (JS vs CSS) all add up to a smooth and manageable experience.

---

There are many ways that CSS can be wrangled and learning and **implementing** "best practices" or new techniques and structures are a few of the ways that large companies maintain their sites.

Comment: Just adding my 5 cents that it's also lots on naming schemes like BEM to manipulate existing styles in an understandable manner to other/new team members: http://getbem.com/introduction/